# How can I use the django shell while the server is running?

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn, digital-ocean, sqlite

I have a django server deployed on digitalocean with gunicorn and nginx.
I followed a tutorial, I think it was [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04).
Because of the tutorial I have django only installed in a virtualenv.

When I developed the server, I used to do stuff in the shell, like checking things in the sqlite database.

Is using the shell a good idea while the server is running, or can it break things?
How can I use the shell, should I activate the venv and the type`python manage.py shell`?

Thx for your help and stay healthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to activate the venv and then I could use the shell.